# click armature deform. but, body mesh goes up!

Tags: rigging

At the end of the rigging process. I select body and slelect all of rigging.
and ctrl+P - click armature deform. But, body mesh goes up.
This is my problem. What is the solution solve this. (Please check my issue on the video.)
https://www.youtube.com/embed/7DrUnsbRpKE

[image]

Comment: Try using CTRL + A to apply the scale and location of the character mesh.

Comment: Thanks. Leo. I try Ctrl+A and apply scale, location. 
But the situation is the same.